# For Loop SetTimeout Works Only 1 Time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have a button with click function below. It has 3 nested for loop, and 1 setTimeout function.

The below loops are looping 5 times. I want below code to work(5x5) total 25 seconds of execution time, and each 5 seconds console output should  be "Waited" printed.

However below code works only 5 seconds, and immediately prints "5 hello". Without changing my for loop structure, how can I make it work as I want?

```
  jQuery("#btn_trendyolStocksSYNC").click(function() {
    for(var product in all){
      var colors = all[product];
      for(var singleColor in colors[0]){
        var size = colors[0][singleColor];
        for(var index in size){
          var singleSize = size[index];
          setTimeout(function (){
            console.log('Waited');
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Edit: I don't use the for loop with indexes, so solutions for number indexed for loops are not working for me.

Comment: All your timers are actually set immediately and executed at the same time. You could potentially use an `await` with a `Promise`, or a nested function to call the next iteration of your timer once one is done.

Comment: @Ivar the for loop types are not similar. I have also seen that question and it doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by adding `await` and a `Promise`:

```
jQuery("#btn_trendyolStocksSYNC").click(async function() {
    for(var product in all){
      var colors = all[product];
      for(var singleColor in colors[0]){
        var size = colors[0][singleColor];
        for(var index in size){
          var singleSize = size[index];
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function (){
            console.log('Waited');
            resolve();
          }, 5000));
        }
      }
    }
});
```

What this does is simply tell your loop to stop and only continue once the Promise object calls its `resolve` parameter function. That way your delay should simply happen before the next iteration. This is the important code:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function (){
      console.log('Waited');
      resolve();
}, 5000));
```

It simply creates a `Promise` that we *will* resolve once the timeout has let 5000 milliseconds pass. Then we tell our loop to simply await that completion before continuing to the next item.

**Note** You also need to add `async` to your handler function, so javascript knows that this function can wait and take as long as it needs to.

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, simply add `async` before your handling function (I have amended the answer to `jQuery("#btn_trendyolStocksSYNC").click(async function() {...`) This is necessary to tell javascript that this function will have some waiting included.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, and it shows -> console.log('Waited') in debugger.

Comment: Sorry I can't test your code locally, this is again my bad - there is a `}` too many in the Promise setup. Amended my answer.

Comment: no worries, it works perfectly fine now. Thank you for the help. I'll now learn about promises, and how it all worked :)

Comment: Its a deep subject but they can be really useful. Be aware that browsers have only recently started support for `async` and `await`, so if you need to support older browsers you might need to transpile your code using something like Babel. (Transpiling will simply add a whole lot of code that makes your code function as intended even on browsers that dont directly support it).

Comment: the reason that I asked this question was, my previous question in my profile. I thought that if I can find the reason why setTimeout only triggers once, I could solve it, but unfortunatelly I couldn't. If you have time, can you take a look at that one too ? :// I'll be very appreciated.

Comment: I checked out your previous question, and since you are using `jQuery.trigger` there is no way to async await here. You are better of creating a general `async function` that you can directly call yourself, passing in an object with the values you need for the function body. That way you can use this same function to register in the `jQuery.on` and you can reuse the code while atill allowing await in your for loop. Its a bit complicated though. Just keep in mind that jQuery was built waaaaaay before `async/await` was even a thing...

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout();` function is **asynchronous**, meaning that your script will not wait for it to finish before moving on. That's why it has a callback.

Try something like this: (not the best method)

```
//delayed loop
var i = 1;
function loop() {
    //wait 5 secs
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
        if(i>5) {
            //cancel
            return;
        }
        loop();
        i++;
        return;
    }, 1000);
    if(i>5) {
        //cancel function
        return;
    }
}
//do the loop
loop();
```

Like what somethinghere said, you could put the `setTimeout` in the `if` statement.

Of course to do something after the loop ends you need a callback function.

Comment: You could simplify this greatly if you do your checks in a different position. AKA `if( i < 5 ) setTimeout(...)` instead of checking after. You could even increment the `i` right there to save another line of code `if( i++ < 5 ) ...` - but in essence, this is indeed how to handle it without the newer async/await. It does require a lot of refactoring on the OP's end.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setInterval and clearInterval.

```
var n=0;
var a = setInterval(()=>{
    console.log("Waited");
    n++; if(n==5){clearInterval(a);}
},5000);
```